# Why the ArrayList is not initialising with runtime input?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on Java Collection Framework , and created a list of size 10 still the program prompting me that the list size is `0`, further if list processed it throws `IndexOfBoundException` of course

I've searched about this but I don't know why it's happening to me

```
    int size =sc.nextInt();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);   
    System.out.println(list+" "+list.size());
```

I expect the output as [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 10 but output is [] 0 .

Comment: you are creating `ArrayList` with initial capacity not size

Comment: The whole point of using a list over an array is the dynamic size, why would you want to define size of list ?

Comment: Stop, document time ... (sorry, it's a long day) - [`ArrayList(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) does not "fill" the underlying buffer, it simple allocates the size buffer - `ArrayList` is backed by an array, so it takes time to resize, providing a initial buffer can help performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize the `List` to a given size with default value, you can use `nCopies`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size,0));
```

Now your `println` statement will output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 10
```

(assuming `size` is `10`).

Comment: We can also use like this  `List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(size, 0);`

Comment: @ashishpawar Not if you want to modify that `list` later, since `nCopies` returns an immutable `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation, it says empty list is created with specified capacity.

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

**What is this capacity and why is it useful?**

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

Comment: yes until you add elements to list it will be empty, if you are fixed about size then go for `Array` so you will get what you want @ashishpawar

Answer (score 0):

The parameter initializes an internal array of a *particular capacity* (the default is actually already 10, if you give no argument)

You must loop to fill up the list with values, and the outer collection of your list starts at size 0

Comment: I've used ` Collections.fill(list,0);` but still same output

Comment: You can't fill an empty collection. You need to manually add elements. You could add null 10 times, then call fill, for example

Comment: If you really want a fixed array, then you want `new int[size]`

Comment: I need to specify initial size that might grow as program further executed but I’ve problem that even accessed first element it says indexOutOfBound exception ?

Comment: Because you didn't add anything yet. There is no initial size for collection subclasses. And like I said, 10 is already the default, and it will grow as you add more than half that size

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    {   
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                 add(0);
             }   
        }
    };
    System.out.println(list+" "+list.size());
```

Now we can have proper size of List and initialised with 0.

Comment: `List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(size, 0);` for shorthand